# svn import command giving error?

Tags: svn, centos

I am trying to import a repository into SVN using:

```
svn import /home/guest/Desktop/first_repo/ file:///var/www/svn/repos/first_one -m "first repository"
```

When I fire this command, I get a big list of added files and finally it exits with the error listed below:

```
svn: Can't move '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-protorevs/1-d.rev' to
'/var/www/svn/repos/db/revs/0/2': Permission denied
```

I changed the permissions of the `repos` directory and all the files in it to 777. I disabled selinux.

Then, I tried the same as `Super User`: it has been added and I am also able to checkout. But, when I try to commit with some changes (as a normal user) I get the same error again:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't move '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-protorevs/1-e.rev' to
'/var/www/svn/repos/db/revs/0/2': Permission denied
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Is `svn import` a must and should it be done as `Super User`? If yes, why I am not able to commit as a normal user? (I am giving 777 permissions)
2. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i got the answer on my own.
The problem is the files in `/var/www/svn/repos/db/transactions` and `/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-protorevs` don't have access permissions. I gave 777 permissions to these folders, but, i forgot to give permissions to the files inside in those folders.

So, Need to check permissions of all the folders and files correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario was creating a new repo on the server and attempting to import from the client.

I compared all the group and user permissions and file permissions against a working repo on same server. Despite all matching, I received the same "can't write..." error repeatedly.

I decided to check the versions of svn on server and client and found a minor mismatch. The server was running 1.7.9 and the client 1.7.19. I went back and created another repo, but did it with the "--pre-1.6-compatible" flag:
        "svnadmin --pre-1.6-compatible create repo-new"

All worked fine after that.